# Hitting "Something went wrong!" with desktop version of APIC Test & Monitor

Tags: apiconnect-test-monitor

Using the v1.0.0 desktop client, downloaded from [here](https://github.com/ibm-apiconnect/test-and-monitor/releases) as per this: -

[IBM API Connect Test and Monitor](https://github.com/ibm-apiconnect/test-and-monitor)

I'm trying/failing to hit a local RESTful endpoint, which is running on the same Mac as that hosting the APIC T&M client.

This is what I see from APIC T&M: -

```
Something went wrong!

Failed to fetch your request; most likely due to network error or invalid hostname.
```

and, in my endpoint's debug: -

```
http2: server: error reading preface from client [::1]:55968: read tcp [::1]:8443->[::1]:55968: read: connection reset by peer
```

I've also tried changing the URL to: -

```
https://127.0.0.1:8443/v1/instances
```

but to no avail.

I **CAN** hit the same endpoint using cURL, openSSL, Postman, Insomnia, SoapUI, Firefox and Chrome, so I don't believe it's the endpoint but .....

Looking at the options to debug the APIC T&M client ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided URL, I suspect the issue you described is caused by the use of HTTPS without a valid certificate. The app currently relies on [Chromium Root Certificate Policy](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy) to validate SSL certificates.

The developer team is currently working on a feature that enables users to ignore unrecognised/self-signed SSL certificates and should be available in the next release.

**Disclaimer**: I'm a member of the IBM API Connect Test and Monitor development team.

Comment: Thanks for the kind feedback, that does make sense, given that we need to force cURL to ignore self-signed certificates ( those for which we don't have the CA signer in the trust chain ), using the _-k_ switch.

I'll await the next release with keen interest :-) 

Thanks again, you rock !